# depthimage_to_laserscan - image convertion error

Tags: ros, xtion, depthimage-to-laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

Getting, what I can only assume is a simple problem to fix but I've yet to find it, with depthimage_to_laser scan using an XTion sensor.

I'm starting up the xtion driver and depthimage_to_laser scan thus:

```
rosrun openni2_camera openni2_camera_node /openni2_camera/deh/image_raw:=/image /openni2_camera/depth/camera_info:=/camera_info

rosrun depthimage_to_laserscan depthimage_to_laserscan
```

But get this error:

"Could not convert depth image to laserscan: scan_height ( 1 pixels) is too large for the image height."

The camera_info topic is reporting (rostopic echo /camera_info):

> header:
> seq: 811175
> stamp:
> secs: 1408516955
> nsecs: 604143184
> frame_id: /openni2_depth_frame
> height: 480
> width: 640
> distortion_model: plumb_bob
> D: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
> K: [570.3422241210938, 0.0, 314.5, 0.0, 570.3422241210938, 235.5, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
> R: [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
> P: [570.3422241210938, 0.0, 314.5, 0.0, 0.0, 570.3422241210938, 235.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]
> binning_x: 0
> binning_y: 0
> roi:
> x_offset: 0
> y_offset: 0
> height: 0
> width: 0
> do_rectify: False

Which to me looks like the frame sizing should be fine. I can view the depth image in rviz with out issue

Does anyone have a suggestion re: what I can check?

UPDATE:

So I've updated the depthimage_to_laserscan code to give me a better idea of what is going on around this error

the if statement:

```
if(scan_height_/2 > cam_model_.cy() || scan_height_/2 > depth_msg->height - cam_model_.cy())
{
  ...
}
```

because after listing the componnet data i get:

```
[ERROR] [1408936282.644193807]: Could not convert depth image to laserscan: scan_height ( 1 pixels) is too large for the image height.
cam_model_.cy 235.5
depth_msg->height 120  
depth_msg->height - cam_model_.cy() -115.5
```

Obviously 0.5 > -115.5

If I take that check put it'll run for a while producing some data then crash with a seg fault.

Any idea on that logic?

Many Thanks

Mark

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190671/depthimage_to_laserscan---image-convertion-error/) by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1834 on 2014-08-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-20**:
did you sudo apt-get install ros-yourdistro-dephtimage-to-laserscan?
I've just install my XtionPro and it work fine

**Comment by [Moda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19573/moda/) on 2014-08-20**:
I'm using hydro, and launch the openni2.launch,

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2014-08-20**:
No this is built from scratch - running on raspberry-pi

**Comment by [anamcarvalho](https://answers.ros.org/users/19590/anamcarvalho/) on 2014-08-24**:
Have you changed anything from the original code of the package? Or any parameter?

**Comment by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) on 2014-08-27**:
@anamcarvalho - nope changed nothing. What depth image size vs camera model size do you get? (This is with and XTion)

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[Fix here](http://answers.ros.org/question/191468/xtion-depth-image-size-problem/?answer=191687#post-id-191687)

---

Originally posted by [MarkyMark2012](https://answers.ros.org/users/2193/markymark2012/) with karma: 1834 on 2014-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0